# passing a function to a function in R

Tags: r

I want to have a function which performs a function (sum, max, min) based on the algo argument. I don't want to use a bunch of if statements though.

how can i do it like the following pseudocode?

```
test_func <- function(num1, num2, algo = sum) {
    return algo(num1, num2)
}
```

Comment: Your function works though `return()` or without return

Comment: Your `test_func` is basically re-implementing `do.call`. `do.call(what = sum, args = list(1, 2))`.

Comment: Does this code not work for you? It seems you've already answered the question. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @MrFlick Not working only because as akrun points out `return` is missing its `()`.